# make tooltip work only in class not in title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

This codes does what i want but by default everywhere on my website where there is title attribute it changes the style which i do not want.

I want it to work in just some places where i assign it.

could someone show me how to?

the css

```
#tooltip {
    background: #C7100C;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    width:20%;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Here is the js

```
(function () {
    var ID = "tooltip", CLS_ON = "tooltip_ON", FOLLOW = true,
    DATA = "_tooltip", OFFSET_X = 20, OFFSET_Y = 10,
    showAt = function (e) {
        var ntop = e.pageY + OFFSET_Y, nleft = e.pageX + OFFSET_X;
        $("#" + ID).html($(e.target).data(DATA)).css({
            position: "absolute", top: ntop, left: nleft
        }).show();
    };
    $(document).on("mouseenter", "*[title]", function (e) {
        $(this).data(DATA, $(this).attr("title"));
        $(this).removeAttr("title").addClass(CLS_ON);
        $("<div id='" + ID + "' />").appendTo("body");
        showAt(e);
    });
    $(document).on("mouseleave", "." + CLS_ON, function (e) {
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).data(DATA)).removeClass(CLS_ON);
        $("#" + ID).remove();
    });
    if (FOLLOW) { $(document).on("mousemove", "." + CLS_ON, showAt); }
}());
```

Comment: With `"*[title]"` you target every element with a title tag. How do you want to assign tooltips to an element?

Comment: Can you show how to not target everywhere? maybe call it by id?  Thanks

Comment: Added an answer. It's better to target a `class` instead of an `id` because you can have multiple elements with the same class, but ids are unique, so no two elements can have the same id.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `"*[title]"` with something like `".make-tooltip"` and assign this class to elements you want to have that tooltip.

This way you don't target *all* elements which have a title, but only those elements, which have the `.make-tooltip` class.

```js
(function () {
    var ID = "tooltip", CLS_ON = "tooltip_ON", FOLLOW = true,
    DATA = "_tooltip", OFFSET_X = 20, OFFSET_Y = 10,
    showAt = function (e) {
        var ntop = e.pageY + OFFSET_Y, nleft = e.pageX + OFFSET_X;
        $("#" + ID).html($(e.target).data(DATA)).css({
            position: "absolute", top: ntop, left: nleft
        }).show();
    };
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".make-tooltip", function (e) {
        $(this).data(DATA, $(this).attr("title"));
        $(this).removeAttr("title").addClass(CLS_ON);
        $("<div id='" + ID + "' />").appendTo("body");
        showAt(e);
    });
    $(document).on("mouseleave", "." + CLS_ON, function (e) {
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).data(DATA)).removeClass(CLS_ON);
        $("#" + ID).remove();
    });
    if (FOLLOW) { $(document).on("mousemove", "." + CLS_ON, showAt); }
}());
```

```css
#tooltip {
    background: #C7100C;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    width:20%;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript;" class="make-tooltip" title="I am a title">I'm a link</a><br>
<a href="javascript;" title="I am a title">I'm a link</a><br>
<a href="javascript;" class="make-tooltip" title="I am a title">I'm a link</a><br>
<a href="javascript;" title="I am a title">I'm a link</a><br>
<a href="javascript;" class="make-tooltip" title="I am a title">I'm a link</a><br>
```

Comment: Strange it looks fine here but when i try it on my site tooltip wont work

Comment: @Lovelyn Did you replace `$(document).on("mouseenter", "*[title]", function (e) {` with `$(document).on("mouseenter", ".make-tooltip", function (e) {` and have you added `class="make-tooltip"` to the elements you want to have a tooltip?

Comment: I am confused, Could you please update your code i would be greatful.

Comment: My code is fine, I was asking if you applied the two differences between my code and yours. Read my answer again ;)

Comment: Oh yes i did but on moreover nothing showing :-D i did add class="make-tooltip"

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, there's not much I can do about that, sorry. If it works in my example, but doesn't work on your page, then the problem is somewhere in the rest of your code.